# Android soft keyboard push only a certain view

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an activity with a custom action bar and a listview, down below is a framelayout containing edittext where user can type whatever text.

my problem is that, when the edittext got focus, the entire layout is pushed up (the custom action bar is no longer visible)

is there a way where only the framelayout with edittext gets pushed up, much like the Facebook comments?

I've seen suggestion wherein I should use `ScrollView` but I'm already using a `ListView`, I don't think `ScrollView` is recommended here.

Also tried using `isScrollContainer=false`, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line before the setContentView() in your onCreate() method,

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this in your manifest file.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```